# How to find the quadratic approximation of a quotient?

Tags: calculus, approximation

How would I find the quadratic approximation of some quotient like tan(x)?

Can I rewrite it as $\tan(x) = \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$, and then find the approximation for sine and cosine separately?

Comment: The quadratic approximation of a quotient is not the quotient of the quadratic approximations (which is not even a quadratic function). It instead involves the first derivative and the second derivative of the whole quotient, which you can find using the quotient rule. It may help to simplify the first derivative before taking the second derivative if possible (it is indeed possible in the case of $\tan$).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it; this is series composition.

Suppose that you want the Taylor series of $$y=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$$ built around $x=0$ up to second order. You have
$$f(x)=f(0)+x f'(0)+\frac{1}{2} x^2 f''(0)+O\left(x^3\right)$$
$$g(x)=g(0)+x g'(0)+\frac{1}{2} x^2 g''(0)+O\left(x^3\right)$$
$$y=\frac{f(0)+x f'(0)+\frac{1}{2} x^2 f''(0)+O\left(x^3\right) }{g(0)+x g'(0)+\frac{1}{2} x^2 g''(0)+O\left(x^3\right) }$$ Now, use the long division to get 
$$y=\frac{f(0)}{g(0)}+\frac{ \left(g(0) f'(0)-f(0) g'(0)\right)}{g(0)^2}x+\frac{
   \left(g(0)^2 f''(0)-2 g(0) f'(0) g'(0)-f(0) g(0) g''(0)+2 f(0) g'(0)^2\right)}{2 g(0)^3}x^2+O\left(x^3\right)$$

Answer (score 4):

I’m not entirely sure if this is what you’re asking, but I suppose you could use the first few terms of the Taylor series

$$\tan x = x + \frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{2x^5}{15} +\cdots $$

for $|x|<\pi/2$. Does that help?

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{align}
f(x) &= \tan x \\
f’(x) &= \sec^2x \\
f’’(x) &= 2\sec(x)\tan(x) \\
\end{align}$$

You should just memorize $f’(x)$, and $f’’(x)$ comes from chain rule.

Assuming we expand the approximation around $x=a$, we’ll use

$$f(x)\approx f(0)+f’(0)\,(x-a)+\frac{f’’(0)\,(x-a)^2}{2}$$

Use

$$\begin{align}
\tan0&=0\\
\sec^20&=1\\
2\sec(0)\tan(0)&=0\\
\end{align}\\$$

Giving you the rather lousy $f(x)\approx x$, hence my recommendation in my other answer.